# How to get specific character in listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox in which my selected products are stored like this ...

'Product name'.padright(30)                       'price' 'quantity'

```
listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString() + " " + 1 );
```

but when I read price of a product it selects price and quantity

```
string currentPriceString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(30), "");

string quantityString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(33), "");
```

I only want price in `currentPriceString` and quantity in `quantityString`

here is complete code of this method

```
private void ProductButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button ProductButton = sender as Button;
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
    int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(ProductButton.Tag);

    Details details = dataAccess.ReadProductDetails(ProductID);

    decimal price = details.Price;

    string foundItem = CheckProductInListBox(details.Name);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundItem))
    {
        string currentPriceString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(30), "");
        decimal currentPriceValue;
        string quantityString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(33), "");
        int quantiy;
        MessageBox.Show(currentPriceString);

        if (Decimal.TryParse(currentPriceString, out currentPriceValue))
        {
            quantiy = Convert.ToInt16(quantityString);

            currentPriceValue += price;
            quantiy++;
            string newItem = details.Name.PadRight(30) + currentPriceValue.ToString()  + quantiy.ToString();

            int index = listBox1.Items.IndexOf(foundItem);
            listBox1.Items[index] = newItem;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString() + " " + 1 );
    }
}

private string CheckProductInListBox(string name)
{
    foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Contains(name))
        {
            return item;
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: From the [`visual-studio`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) tag's wiki: "Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio. Consider tagging the exact technology area your question links to and also tagging a more specific version of Visual Studio. Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question."

Comment: Can  you share one sample value of `foundItem`?

Comment: it returns the product name which already exists in listbox

Comment: Why not create your own Product type which would hold all these values. Override the ToString Method to show it in the listbox the way you want. Then just get the property values from the selecteditem when you need it.

Comment: Another option that would simplify things would be to use a listview and have columns for each of your values that you're currently concatenating into a listbox. Much cleaner look IMO.

Comment: You are looking for `DataGridView`

Comment: have you tried `string currentPriceQuantityString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(30), "");` and then `string[] strArray = currentPriceQuantityString.Split()` and then `string currentPriceString = strArray[0]` and `string quantityString = strArray[1]` ?

Comment: This is just the wrong way to go about it.  ListBox is a gadget to display info,  always strive to separate the data and the view.  You just need a `List<detail>` to keep track of all of the properties of an item in the box.  Also the next step to take advantage of data binding.

Answer (score 0):

On replacing (`foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(33), "");`), you are just removing the name part from the string, so the price and quantity will be there for sure.

You should can try this code,

```
// suppose your found text is like this,
//foundItem = "AMIT".PadRight(30) + "200" + " " + "1";
```

You can get price and quantity separately like below:

```
string currentPriceQuantityString = foundItem.Replace(details.Name.PadRight(30), "");
//currentPriceQuantityString => "200 1"

string[] strArray = currentPriceQuantityString.Split();

string currentPriceString = strArray[0]; //currentPriceString => "200"
string quantityString = strArray[1];     //quantityString => "1"
```

---

Side note:

I guess your line:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString() + " " + 1 );
```

..should be:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(details.Name.PadRight(30) + details.Price.ToString() + " " + "1" );
```